# Difference between $app->Redirect and $app->response->redirect in Slim

Tags: php, redirect, slim

This question is slightly ambiguous, so sorry about that.

Basically, I'm writing a website using Slim as the framework, but I have noticed that there are two different (but common) ways to redirect. Using `$app->redirect()` and `$app->response->redirect();`

From what I can see in the documentation, there is nothing to indicate the difference between the two, besides that `$app->redirect()` will throw an exception (That Slim will catch), or which to use where. And research into the subject has only revealed that `$app->response->redirect()` should be used in MiddleWare, but no other information. So my question is when and where should you use the `$app->response->redirect();` over the `$app->redirect()` or vice versa.

Comment: What version of Slim are you using? Did you check the [documentation](http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/helpers/#redirect)?

Comment: 2.6, and yes i did read the documentation, and saw nothing of relevance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$app->redirect()` is only a helper function. It delegates your call to `$app->response->redirect()`.

See Code on [Github](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/2.x/Slim/Slim.php#L1102):

```php
//Slim.php

public function redirect($url, $status = 302)
{
    $this->response->redirect($url, $status);
    $this->halt($status);
}
```